# Scan all classes for a given custom attribute

Tags: class, delphi, attributes, delphi-xe

I'm looking for a way of scanning all loaded classes for classes which contain a custom attribute, if possible, without using RegisterClass().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

at first you have to create `TRttiContext`, then get all loaded classes using `getTypes`. after that you can filter types by `TypeKind = tkClass`;
next step is to enumerate attributes and check if it has your attribute;

attribute and test-class delcaration:

```
unit Unit3;

interface
type
    TMyAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
    end;

    [TMyAttribute]
    TTest = class(TObject)

    end;

implementation

initialization
    TTest.Create().Free();  //if class is not actually used it will not be compiled

end.
```

and then find it:

```
program Project3;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, rtti, typinfo, unit3;

type TMyAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)

     end;

var ctx : TRttiContext;
    t : TRttiType;
    attr : TCustomAttribute;
begin
    ctx := TRttiContext.Create();

    try
        for t  in ctx.GetTypes() do begin
            if t.TypeKind <> tkClass then continue;

            for attr in t.GetAttributes() do begin
                if attr is TMyAttribute then begin
                    writeln(t.QualifiedName);
                    break;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        ctx.Free();
        readln;
    end;
end.
```

output is `Unit3.TTest`

> Call RegisterClass to register a class with the streaming system.... Once classes are registered, they can be loaded or saved by the component streaming system.

so if you don't need *component streaming* (just find classes with some attribute), there is no need to `RegisterClass`

Comment: For what it's worth, the line `ctx := TRttiContext.Create();` is simply not needed. You can happily delete it!

Comment: Your sample code is not complete. Provide the class to be annotated with TMyAttribute.

Comment: @menjaraz No, that's not needed. This is answer is complete.

Comment: @menjaraz Done :) 
@DavidHeffernan in this case `Create` is not needed, but if I use ctx few times then there is not need to hold old context data, so I prefer `Create` it always (:

Comment: @teran It's created on demand no matter what, so if you want to clear out the old then call `Free` when you are done. I personally find this style (as demonstrated here by Embarcadero) of making records look like classes to be rather misleading. I would rather they didn't use `Create` and `Free` in records because it makes a reader of the code things that `ctx` is a heap allocated, reference type. And it is anything but.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, it answers the question but I prefer to go beyond that by adding a duly annotated class. I think of newbies searching some resources related to the topic here on SO.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the new RTTI functionality exposed by the Rtti unit.

```
var
  context: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  attr: TCustomAttribute;
  method: TRttiMethod;
  prop: TRttiProperty;
  field: TRttiField;
begin
  for typ in context.GetTypes do begin
    for attr in typ.GetAttributes do begin
      Writeln(attr.ToString);
    end;

    for method in typ.GetMethods do begin
      for attr in method.GetAttributes do begin
        Writeln(attr.ToString);
      end;
    end;

    for prop in typ.GetProperties do begin
      for attr in prop.GetAttributes do begin
        Writeln(attr.ToString);
      end;
    end;

    for field in typ.GetFields do begin
      for attr in field.GetAttributes do begin
        Writeln(attr.ToString);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This code enumerates attributes associated with methods, properties and fields, as well as with types. Naturally you will want to do more than `Writeln(attr.ToString)`, but this should give you an idea for how to proceed. You can test for your specific attribute in the normal way

```
if attr is TMyAttribute then
  ....
```