# Is it possible to get the index of class property?

Tags: delphi, properties

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  ...
  public
    ...
    property P1: Integer Index 1 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    property P2: Integer Index 2 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    property P3: Integer Index 3 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    ...
  end;
```

Is it possible to get the index of class property? For example, something like

```
  I := IndexOfProperty(TMyClass.P2);
```

Comment: @JerryDodge - I need index of public property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the RTTI, to get the index of a property. depending of you Delphi version you can use `GetPropInfo` method (only for published properties) or access such info via the `TRttiInstanceProperty` class

Try this sample.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils,
  TypInfo;

type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    function GetInteger(const Index: Integer): Integer;
    procedure SetInteger(const Index, Value: Integer);

  public
    property P1: Integer Index 1 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    property P2: Integer Index 2 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
    property P3: Integer Index 3 read GetInteger write SetInteger;
  end;



{ TMyClass }

function TMyClass.GetInteger(const Index: Integer): Integer;
begin

end;

procedure TMyClass.SetInteger(const Index, Value: Integer);
begin

end;


var
  LRttiInstanceProperty   : TRttiInstanceProperty;
  LRttiProperty : TRttiProperty;
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  LPropInfo : PPropInfo;
begin
 try
   LPropInfo:= GetPropInfo(TMyClass, 'P1'); //only works for published properties.
   if Assigned(LPropInfo) then
    Writeln(Format('The index of the property %s is %d',[LPropInfo.Name, LPropInfo.Index]));


   Ctx:= TRttiContext.Create;
   try
     LRttiProperty:=  Ctx.GetType(TMyClass).GetProperty('P2');
     if Assigned(LRttiProperty) and (LRttiProperty is TRttiInstanceProperty) then     
     begin
      LRttiInstanceProperty := TRttiInstanceProperty(LRttiProperty);
      Writeln(Format('The index of the property %s is %d',[LRttiProperty.Name, LRttiInstanceProperty.Index]));
     end;
   finally
     Ctx.Free;
   end;

 except
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Comment: You don't need to create an instance of the class in order to use `GetPropInfo()`. You can pass the class type instead of an object pointer.  Also, `TRttiInstanceProperty` has its own `Index` property, you don't need to use `PropInfo.Index`.

Comment: You mention "(only for published properties)" but yet the example is public properties...

Comment: @JerryDodge, I know that, The OP must modify the class and declare as published the properties in order to use the `GetPropInfo` function.

Comment: @PRUZ - I have an additional question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722394/is-it-possible-to-get-the-index-of-class-property-2

Answer (score 6):

A property's RTTI contains the index.  Your properties are declared as `public`, so they are not accessible via the older style RTTI provided by the `TypInfo` unit.  However, they are accessible via the newer style RTTI provided by the `Rtti` unit (D2010 and later only):

```
uses
  Rtti;

var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  I := (Ctx.GetType(TMyClass).GetProperty('P2') as TRttiInstanceProperty).Index;
end;
```

Had your properties been declared as `published` instead, then you could use `TypInfo` RTTI:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := GetPropInfo(TMyClass, 'P2').Index;
end;
```

Comment: But he can use $RTTI pragma to make public properties also covered for TypeInfo, can't he ?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - I have an additional question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722394/is-it-possible-to-get-the-index-of-class-property-2

Comment: @Arioch'The - Delphi XE4, `{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPublic, vcPublished]) PROPERTIES([vcPublic, vcPublished])}` but `GetPropInfo()` does not work for public props !?

Comment: @Branko if i only knew... personally i just cannot get class properties enumerated at all! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495258/